# ¿Como puedo pausar el progarma mientras tomo entrada en java?

Tags: java, input, scanner

Estuve buscando una respuesta por todos lados pero no la encuentro. En todos los lenguajes de programación que conozco (Python, lua, C++), cuando ejecutas la función de tomar entrada, todo lo que esta abajo no se ejecuta hasta que toques enter, pero en java, ese no es el caso (por lo menos usando los Scanner):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class index {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("TEST");
        System.out.print(entrada);
    }
}
```

Si uno intenta correr el código, el mensaje de "TEST" sale  al principio, lo cual me trae problemas cuando intento poner otro scanner abajo,

Answer (score 1):

En Java es igual, el programa se pausa cuando se pide ingreso de datos.

Lo que sucede es que no estás pidiendo la entrada, solo has creado un objeto de tipo `Scanner` y lo has guardado en la variable `entrada`.

Para leer un dato debes usar una de las funciones de lectura como `nextLine()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("TEST");
        System.out.print(entrada.nextLine());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes agregar un mensaje para que sirva de guia para el usuario que este utilizando el programa, de esta manera seria mas dinamico e interactivo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("TEST");
    System.out.println("\n\tPRESIONA ENTER PARA CONTINUAR");
    scan.nextLine();

}
```